# Reset view controller view using StoryBoard in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, uistoryboard

I have taken a navigation controller in StoryBoard and its root view controller I am doing some animation on images such that it goes out from screen, its perfectly working fine first time, but when I push to another navigation and pop to root view, animations doesn't happened because view already stores last instance.
 My question is: is it possible to load the view again from storyboard by destroying last view and calling animation again.
 I do not want to set the frames again programmatically because there are too many objects.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to write your animation code in viewWillAppear method.